# Problem while searching for a user name

Tags: bug, search

I'm trying to search [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2580523/deepak-rai) user by his name, Deepak Rai. But when I'm searching, I'm not getting his profile. This is what I'm getting:

[image]

The search should show that user as well with pink color Avatar.

Comment: Assuming you're referring to [this user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2580523/deepak-rai), they have two spaces in the middle of their user name.